# JS select length without ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, variable-length

I'm trying to collect the length of several `select`. How can I know the length of each select? The way I found is `$('#mylist option').length` which seems not feasible in this case since I don't have IDs for each select. The `console.log` shown below always return "1" even though there are select with multiple lines.

JS code:

```
$('#severalStores').find('.selectLimitInformation').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).length); //Always return "1"
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="row form-horizontal" id="severalStores">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row form-horizontal">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Store AAA:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select class="form-control selectLimitInformation">
                    @foreach (...) //data from ViewBag
                    {
                        <option value="@storeLimit.info">@storeLimit.description</option>
                    }
                    <option value="0">Not available</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-horizontal">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Store BBB:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select class="form-control selectLimitInformation">
                    @foreach (...) //data from ViewBag
                    {
                        <option value="@storeLimit.info">@storeLimit.description</option>
                    }
                    <option value="0">Not available</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        //Several other select
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason you're using jQuery? But even with that: both plain JS and jQuery use CSS query selectors, so if you want "all select elements", then you literally query for that: ```$(`select`)``` or ```document.querySelectorAll(`select`)```.

Comment: ...or `document.querySelectorAll("select .selectLimitInformation")`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans jQuery is part of the project

Comment: @rd1218 don't tell "me", tell everyone by putting that in your post and adding the jQuery tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it.

First, you loop through the selects. You don't need to use find in your case. Then in your loop you do use find to find the length of options that are children of the select.

```js
$('#severalStores .selectLimitInformation').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).find("option").length); //Always return "1"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row form-horizontal" id="severalStores">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row form-horizontal">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Store AAA:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select class="form-control selectLimitInformation">
                       <option value="@storeLimit.info">@storeLimit.description</option>
                    <option value="0">Not available</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row form-horizontal">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Store BBB:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <select class="form-control selectLimitInformation">
                        <option value="@storeLimit.info">@storeLimit.description</option>
                    <option value="0">Not available</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        //Several other select
    </div>
</div>
```